# Jquery click function not working for all the ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have created a page which contains all the products from the database, and this is dynamic page. Columns are created in loop. Whenever user clicks the product i am fetching the product id which is unique, however this is working only for one product, for next product even if click the function is not triggered. below is the code for reference.

1. {{ album.product_name }}
         Category : {{ album.product_category }}
         Price : {{ album.product_price }}
2. $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#k').click(function(){
               var a  = $('#custId').val();
               alert(a)
               console.log(a)
           });

This is working perfectly fine for the first product only i.e the first product from the loop. for rest the click function is not working. Please help!

Below is the HTML code:

```
<div class="card-body"> 
    <a href="#" id="k">
        <img src="qph.fs.quoracdn.net/…" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="90px" width="85px" id="k">
    </a> 
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ album.product_name }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Category : {{ album.product_category }}</p>
    <p class="card-text">Price : {{ album.product_price }}</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="custId" value={{ album.id }}> 
</div>
```

Comment: Below is the html code

<div class="card-body">
      <a href="#"  id="k"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e646c987b3dcf11c9329af5070847f92.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="90px" width="85px" id="k"></a>
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ album.product_name }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Category : {{ album.product_category }}</p>
      <p class="card-text">Price : {{ album.product_price }}</p>

       <input type="hidden" id="custId"  value={{ album.id }}>
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID. Consider adding a common class name to all the target elements, say `myClass`, then you can bind the desired event using:

```
$('.myClass').click(function(){ 
    //your code here...
});
```

Explanation: The browser assumes you only have one element with an id of `k` (because is should be like so by convention), therefore `$("#k")` will only target the first element with that ID.

Comment: One thing i noticed now is that the first object's id is only returned wherever i click.